# react-sortable-tree not rendering right

Tags: reactjs

My simplest possible react-sortable-tree example looks horrible. I'm forced to use 2.0.1 - not sure if that's relevant.

The treeData is the same as what's here: https://frontend-collective.github.io/react-sortable-tree/

Code:

```
<div className={sortableTreeArea}>
    <SortableTree
        treeData={treeData} onChange={this.updateViewFields}
    />
</div>

sortableTreeArea: {
    height: '100%'
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: What is the value of `treeData`?

Comment: Did you import css ? `import 'react-sortable-tree/style.css';`

Comment: I hadn't imported the styles - should have read the documentation more carefully. Sorted now thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to import styles:

```
import 'react-sortable-tree/style.css'
```

at the top of the page